# HTML submit vs. select

Tags: html, forms, select, submit

I was trying to different solutions for changing languages in my website.

The first was was using a `<select>` dropdown menu and is working fine.

The second approach was to include country flags, which are clickable to change the language.
But this isn't working with my code.

```
   <form action="<?php if (isset($_GET['nav'])){ echo "index.php?nav=" . $_GET['nav'];} else {echo "index.php";} ?>" method="post" id=          "language" >
    <label>Select language: </label>

    <input type="submit" style="background-image: url(./img/lang_de_s.png)" class="languageButton" value="de"  />
    <input type="submit" style="background-image: url(./img/lang_en_s.png)" class="languageButton" value="en"  />

     <select name="language" class="dropdown" onchange="submit();">
        <option value="en"<?php  echo ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'en')?' selected="selected"':''; ?>>English</option>
        <option value="de"<?php  echo ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'de')?' selected="selected"':''; ?>>Deutsch</option>
      </select> 
    </form>
```

So what am I doing wrong with my buttons so the form is not send correctly?
And additinally it would be nice to make the value property of the button invisible. SO the "en" text is not visible on the image. How could I achieve that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: Sry saved a lil too early. I updated the question

Comment: Your input elements don't have a `name` attribute, so they won't submit any value to the server.

Comment: I wonder why don't you wrap an `<a href>` tag around an `<image>` tag? This will make things easier

Comment: Can they have the same name attribute or does it have to be unique? 
I am not working with an href because I want to keep my url things clean. (Use POST not GET) I guess it will get confusing after 3 or 4 parameters.

Comment: Adding `name="language"` did the job.
Post it as answer so I can accept it.
Is there also a solution for hiding the `value` attribute on my image now?

Comment: I just set the fonts `color` opacity to zero. `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment above, your input elements don't have a `name` attribute.  Add that attribute and the value will be submitted correctly.